# Which algorithm should I use to optimize my code?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I have a Array A of N elements . I have to perform Q query in it. At every query i choose an index I(0-based) and does the following

```
for j = I+1 to N:
  if A[j]<A[i]:
      A[j]=0
```

Note : the queries are not independent of each other.

## INPUT:

1. First line contains N(no of elements in the array ) and Q (no.of query)
2. Second line contains N space seperated intergers
3. Q space seperated integers denoting chosen index in each query

---

```
5 2 
4 3 4 3 2
3 2
```

## Output:

```
4 3 4 0 0
```

## Explanation:

1. Array after 1st query : {4,3,4,3,0}
2. Array after 2nd query : {4,3,4,0,0}

I have tried brute force solution that takes O(n*q).Here is what I have done it .

```py
n,q = map(int,input().split())
A = list(map(int,input().split()))
query = list(map(int,input().split()))

for i in range(len(query)):
    for j in range(query[i]+1,n):
        if A[j]<A[query[i]]:
            A[j] = 0

print(A)
```

I want to do the above problem in less than O(n*q). Is it possible . Can you tell we which algorithm to use it .

Comment: Rajan, how you are getting result {4,3,4,3,0} after first query? Can you demo that?

Comment: I = 3 Which means A[I] = 3 , Since it is o-based index.Now runnig the loop from j= i+1 to N , Which means 4 to 5. When j==4 . A[J] <A[I] That is 2<3 Hence A[4] ==0

Comment: what is o-based index? I don't find any such terms in google. I think you have to make your problem more clear.

Comment: How come I = 3?

Comment: Zero based index. The query are 3 2. Which are Index , Taking first query 3 , Hence I=3

Comment: what is the use of first row 5 2?

Comment: The First line contains N and Q . no of elements in the array and no.of query

Comment: @parasjain, is there an online judge where I can submit my solution and check if it is correct?

Comment: @KonstantinYovkov I am sorry i saw this question in a competetion which is not online now . Can you please guide me to reduce the time complexity

Comment: @parasjain, yes, I posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an auxiliary array of size `N`, each element of which will be `1` if there was a query with value `i`, or `0`, otherwise.

Then, we can iterate the auxiliary array and track what is the **maximum** of `x[i]` values, for which there was a query.

On each step (lets name it `current`), if this maximum is more than the value of the current element, update the element to `0` - that means that there was a query with value `p`, where `x[p] > x[current]` and thus, `x[current]` was set to `0`.

This way we achieve an overall runtime of `O(n + q)` and `O(n)` of memory.

Lets run through the example:

```
n = 5
q = 2 
x = {4, 3, 4, 3, 2}
q[0] = 3 
q[1] = 2
```

Initially, our auxiliary array a would be `a = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}`.

The first query is `q[0] = 3`, thus we update `a[3] = 1`, because everything after `x[3]` must be compared with `x[3]` and updated if necessary.

The second query is `q[1] = 2`, thus we update `a[2] = 1`, because everything after `x[2]` must be compared with `x[2]` and updated if necessary. This now overlaps with the previous query and in order to combine them and decide whether we should update an element to `0` or not, we should take the maximum of `x[2]` and `x[3]`.

Finally, we iterate through `a` and track the current maximum value of `x` that is part of a query. We update `x[i]` to `0` if is *affected* by any query and its value is less that the maximum of the queries that affect it.

My code is in Java, but I hope it's self explanatory:

```
int n = in.nextInt(), q = in.nextInt();
int[] x = new int[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  x[i] = in.nextInt();
}
int[] a = new int[n];
while (q-- > 0) {
  int i = in.nextInt();
  a[i] = 1;
}
int max = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  if (a[i] == 1) {
    max = Math.max(max, x[i]);
  }
  if (x[i] < max) {
    x[i] = 0;
  }
}
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  out.print(x[i]);
  out.print(' ');
}
```